# Azure Function Scaling way to many instances

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We are using Azure functions and we have a few in one app service plan that seems to scale far to many instances.  Often 10 or more.  The cpu is 0 on most and < 1 on a couple.  memory is only 40% used.  It does have 500ms dependencies because some call api's in our datacenter and a table storage queue.  Honestly its only a few thousand calls a day.  It should run on one instance without any issues.  Sometimes it scales down but it doesn't seem to correlate to load.

I don't want to force it to one instance, usage will grow over time.

Any way to tell in app insights why???  Or a way to be more granular in scaling?

[image]

*** EDIT ***
It's the queue for some reason.  Still working on it.

Comment: You can get more insights into why scaling decisions are being made, by enabling the scale controller logs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling#runtime-scaling - I've used this in the past to identify why a function on a consumption plan wasn't scaling up.